# Objective-C, Delegate as Adapter Pattern: who is the adaptee?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, design-patterns, delegates

I've read more than once that the Delegate Pattern used in Cocoa is an implementation of the Adaptern Pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).
They share the same intent, which is: let two objects with incompatible interfaces to work with each other.
The delegate object is the Adapter, because it adopts a protocol required by a client, the class that requires the protocol and has a weak reference to a delegate is the Client (so, this would be a class of the Cocoa framework).
My question is: who is the Adaptee? The delegate pattern doesn't wrap itself around any object, from what I've seen, who is the object that needs to be adapted?

Comment: Data sources would be one example of an adapter pattern in objective-c.

Comment: The intent behind delegation is specialization without subclassing. The app delegate, for example, modifies the behavior of the application object without requiring a `UIApplication` subclass. Delegate objects often do implement protocols which let them fit two objects together, like a table and it's data, but the adapter pattern is really about classes whose primary function is converting from one interface to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution in the official documentation, as I suspected there is no adaptee:
https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW5

Answer (score 6):

Delegates are not really an example of the Adapter pattern. Protocols would be closer, but the best way to implement the Adapter pattern in Objective C is to create a new object that contains the object you want to adapt and uses it to serve a client.

Categories are another way of implementing the Adapter pattern, but they have some limitations. You can't override the implementation of existing methods in a category, and you can't add additional instance variables to a class with a category. However you can implement properties using associated objects and you can also add new instance methods.

You can also use multiple inheritance to implement the Adapter pattern in languages like C++ that offer it, but Objective-C does not support multiple inheritance.

A simple example of an Adapter using a category that I use in my projects is as follows:

Interface Builder (IB) includes a feature called "User Defined Runtime Attributes" that lets you set properties on your custom interface objects using Key Value Coding (KVC). It lets you specify a limited number of data types (ints, floats, bools, points, rects, UIColors, and a few others.) 
You can use User Defined Runtime Attributes to set the border width and corner radius on a view's layer, and you SHOULD be able to use it to change the layer's border color or background color. However, layer colors are specified as CGColors, and UIViews use UIColors. Since IB only accepts UIColors in a User Defined Runtime Attribute, it doesn't work.

To fix this, I created a category of CALayer called CALayer+setUIColor. It has 2 methods, setBorderUIColor and setBackgroundUIColor. Those methods are very simple. They take UIColors as input, and simply convert the UIColor to a CGColor and set the layer's border color or background color.

You can see an early version of this category in my github project [**KeyframeViewAnimations**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/KeyframeViewAnimations).

Comment: "Categories are another way of implementing the Adapter pattern,"
Nope, that's the Decorator.
The Adapter is about modifying an existing interface to make it compatible with another interface; whereas the Decorator is about adding functionality without altering the interface of that given type.
With categories in ObjC (and extensions in Swift) you implement the Decorator pattern - the Apple way.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that is a completely wrong view of the Cocoa delegate pattern.

The object needing a delegate is intentionally left incomplete. But instead of having an abstract class and adding the required functionality through subclassing, we add the required functionality by providing another object, the delegate.

Nowadays people will more and more switch from using delegate objects to providing the required functionality by passing one or more blocks instead.

Comment: by one or more blocks you mean 'adapter' pattern? Similar to protocol oriented in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

> Delegation is not a strict implementation of the Decorator pattern.
> The host (delegating) object does not wrap an instance of the class it
> wants to extend; indeed, it’s the other way around, in that the
> delegate is specializing the behavior of the delegating framework
> class. There is no sharing of interface either, other than the
> delegation methods declared by the framework class.
>
> Delegation in Cocoa is also part of the Template Method pattern
> (Template Method).

**Source:** https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW19

Answer (score -2):

The DELEGATE object is Adapter because:

It uses special protocol of special object and wrap it to itself special protocol.

Comment: What you are saying there is devoid of any meaning.

Comment: please, reformulate your answer because is not properly written in English